# How to programmatically fill a textBox from wx.html2.WebView wxpython object?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

[PROBLEM]
I want to write programmatically some text inside wx.html2.WebView wxpython object.

[CODE]

```
import wx
import wx.html2    
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'test')
browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(frame)
browser.LoadURL("https://www.python.org/")

browser.RunScript("document.getElementById('id-search-field').value = test")          

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[CURRENT OUTPUT]:
nothing gets filled inside the textBox

[DESIREDT OUTPUT]:
the text should be written down inside the textBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register an event handler so that `browser.RunScript` is called after the page load. Otherwise, `RunScript` will have no effect because the page will not be ready when the function is called.

In addition to that, `test` should be quoted to denote a string in javascript:

```
import wx
import wx.html2

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'test')
browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(frame)
def loaded(e):
    if e.GetURL() == 'about:blank':  # Skip if it's a blank page.
        return
    browser.RunScript("document.getElementById('id-search-field').value = 'test'")
browser.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, loaded)
browser.LoadURL("https://www.python.org/")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```